# Why can't I offer a bounty on my question?

Tags: support, bounties

I asked the question [4166114](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166114/xbap-missing-texts-in-published-version) more than two days ago (Fri evening CET), but still cannot offer a bounty. Did anything in the bounty system change or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have an active bounty on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229395) question. As far as I know, you can have only one at a time.